# Running total not aggregating on line chart

Tags: powerbi, cumulative-line-chart

A table with some sales data has an associated running total measure. When viewed in Data view of PowerBi Desktop the data does reflect an aggregated total.

[image: Power Bi Running Total]

However when applied to a line chart the running total is simply the monthly totals. The expectation would be that a running total never decreases (assuming only positive sales) and that the line chart would reflect the values in the measure. So month by month should actually be 500, 1500, 3000.

[image]

**Update 1: As per Foxans suggestion - same result:**

[image]

**Update 2: Works when using an index instead of a date (dd/MM/yyyy):**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [ISONORAFTER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/isonorafter-function-dax) filter should be based on `Date` instead of `Spend` for a running total (Or in the absence of a date column, should be the column which can identify the order you're trying to summarize, e.g. an incremental `index`), i.e.

```
Spend running total in Date = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Spend[Spend]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(Spend),
        ISONORAFTER(Spend[Date], MAX(Spend[Date]), DESC)
    )
)
```

[image: results]

It's causing some confusion here because your sample data in `Spend` column is coincidentally in ascending order of values (100 -> 200 -> 300). If you update it to some random data, you'll notice it won't work in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't work either. Same result.

Comment: @rism Updated. It should be `ALLSELECTED(Spend)` instead of `ALLSELECTED(Spend[Date])`. Otherwise, the filter will be applied on `Date`, and that's why it's filtered to month when the running total is calculated.

Comment: Thanks. One of those times when the mistake was worth it as a few things clicked into place.

Comment: Annoyingly this doesn't work if any date is repeated e.g. if it has two entries for a given day, the formula is rejected - "A single value for column spends cannot be determined" - If I then use either MIN or MAX as an aggregate - i get the same value as if I were summing - In other words no running total just totals for the day / time period. How do I get the running totals even when there are  repeated dates? It seems like this would require a pre-computed, consolidated  data source.. but then if i wanted to split on category i would require a data source per category?

Comment: If that's the case it's better to have a separate date dimension to work with. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627067/calculate-annual-total-from-monthly-total-using-measure-in-power-bi) helps.